# Apache 2.4.x and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have some troubles setting up Wordpress with Apache 2.4.x

Here's my situation. 
I have an installed Wordpress, running smoothly. 
I'm trying to change the permalinks, from the plain option (www.whatever.com/?p=xyz) to the Post name option (www.whatever.com/sample-post/)

.htaccess is created and Wordpress is able to manage/modify it.

When I switch to the Post name option, I can reach the homepage, but every other pages gives me a 404 error. I've checked the configuration, and in my apache2.conf, I saw this :

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
      Options Indexes
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So I added a Directory in my virtualhost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/mywebsite/
        ServerName      www.whatever.com
        ServerAlias     whatever.com
        <Directory /var/www/html/mywebsite/>
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/whatever.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/whatever.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

With this current configuration, the problem is the same. 
If I change the

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

It works ! BUT.. I can't reach the admin part of Wordpress anymore, it keeps redirecting me to the homepage. "AllowOverride all" does the same.

**EDIT :** My .htaccess is empty when I'm using the default configuration.
When I switch to Post name, it gets rewritten like this :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I don't really know what to do here, anyone faced that kind of issue ?

Comment: What's in your .htaccess file?

Comment: When configured as plain, it's empty. When configured as Post name : https://pastebin.com/5ht3cJDs

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a second directory options in my virtualhost configuration :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mywebsite/wp-admin/>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```